# Bundle issue when installin gem from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, docker, rubygems

I have issue with installing gems from Github on Docker. Windows 10 pro.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'kaminari', git: 'https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari', branch: 'master'
```

Error:

```
     Git error: command `git clone --no-checkout --quiet
    "/bundle_box/cache/bundler/git/kaminari-afd5cc7513de17a7e5e6421480370a0b7ec57040"
    "/bbox/bundler/gems/kaminari-27a0c850b50a"` in directory /App has failed.
    If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
    '/box/cache/bundler/
    git/kaminari-afd5cc7513de17a7e5e6421480370a0b7ec57040'
```

I try removing this cache directory. But every time same error

Comment: Is that all the error log? Are there any other errors?

Comment: no there is no other errors. Btw its fixed after removing git address.